# Trait 'Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable' not found

Tags: laravel, google-authenticator

I'm using `pragmarx/google2fa` Laravel package for implementing Google Two-Factor Authentication on my Laravel app. It is working fine but I am getting this error after keying the OTP password - corre[image]

```
<?php

namespace PragmaRX\Google2FALaravel\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class LoginSucceeded
{
use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

public $user;

/**
 * Create a new event instance.
 *
 * @param $user
 */
public function __construct($user)
{
    $this->user = $user;
}
```

}

Is there a way an alternate way for this for Laravel 5.3.xx version?

Comment: Do also add the code where it is used.

Comment: Sorry. Post updated.

Comment: Did you try `composer du`?

Comment: I did. Still there. I think the `Dispatchable` is not available for Laravel 5.3. Looking for a workaround for this.

Comment: It wasn't introduced until Laravel 5.6. It also isn't available in Lumen right up to 5.8.

Answer (score 0):

`Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable` was included on Laravel 5.4.

In fact I see in the Readme that `pragmarx/google2fa` requires Laravel 5.4+ to run.

Sorry!